# Sharp corners in Metafont?

Tags: fonts, metafont

The source code of the Computer Modern slash is:

```
cmchar "Virgule (slash)";
beginchar("/",9u#,body_height#,paren_depth#);
italcorr body_height#*slant-.5u#;
adjust_fit(0,0); pickup rule.nib;
rt x1=hround(w-u)+eps; top y1=h+eps;
lft x2=hround u-eps; bot y2=-d-eps;
draw z1--z2;  % diagonal
penlabels(1,2); endchar;
```

The corners are round. I would like to have sharp corners (but the same thickness); the slash shold be a parallelogramm. I found out that `crisp.nib` draws sharp corners but it has to be used with `pos1 ... pos2`. So I tried:

```
cmchar "Virgule (slash)";
beginchar("/",9u#,body_height#,paren_depth#);
italcorr body_height#*slant-.5u#;
adjust_fit(0,0); pickup crisp.nib;
pos1(rule_thickness+2eps,-45); pos2(rule_thickness+2eps,-45);
rt x1=hround(w-u)+eps; top y1=h+eps;
lft x2=hround u-eps; bot y2=-d-eps;
draw z1--z2;  % diagonal
penlabels(1,2); endchar;
```

But the slash disappears, it is only a onedimensional line, now. What is wrong?

There are some Metafont tutorials but I did not find answers to some other questions:

- What are `crisp.nib`, `fine.nib`, `rule.nib` exactly?
- Why do some `.nib`s need assignments like `pos1(...); pos2(...), ...` and others not? Which ones do need that?
- What is the difference between `fill` and `fill stroke`?
- What are the arguments of `pos1(...)` exactly and how to find out the right values?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to read "Volume E: Computer Modern Typefaces"...   https://www.abebooks.co.uk/9780201134469/Computers-Typesetting-Volume-Computer-Modern-0201134462/plp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't immediately answer the "What is wrong?" question, but you can get much of the detail that answers the other questions in the book [*Volume E: Computer Modern Typefaces*, D. Knuth, 1986](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/abcde.html#abcde), and in particular the appendix that explains `cmbase.mf`.   If you don't have access to the book, you can get some idea of what it going on by reading the source, which you should find in your local TeX tree at `..texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmbase.mf`

#### Nibs

The `.nib` variables are all copies of the built-in `pencircle` pen scaled to useful sizes:

- `crisp.nib` is scaled to the value of the `crisp` parameter, which sets the diameter of serif corners
- `tiny.nib` is scaled to `tiny`, which sets the diameter of rounded corners
- `fine.nib` is scaled to `fine`, which sets the diameter of sharply rounded corners

These are the three main pens used to draw Computer Modern.  The parameters are set differently for roman, italic, bold, and so on.

There is also `rule.nib` which is also a copy of `pencircle` scaled to `rule_thickness` -- this is a special-purpose pen used to draw maths symbols like `+`, `/`, and `=`.

#### The `pos()` macro

The `pos` macro is a generalization of the `penpos` macro in plain MF.  It is defined like this:

```
newinternal currentbreadth;
vardef pos@#(expr b,d) =
 if known b: if b<=currentbreadth: errmessage "bad pos"; fi fi
 (x@#r-x@#l,y@#r-y@#l)=(b-currentbreadth,0) rotated d;
 x@#=.5(x@#l+x@#r); y@#=.5(y@#l+y@#r) enddef;
```

The arguments are a suffix `@#` and two expressions `b` = breadth, and `d` = rotation.  And it uses a global internal variable called `currentbreadth` which keeps track of the breadth of the current pen.

If you unpick the macro, you will see that it creates two linked sets of three variables: `x@#`, `x@#l`, `x@#r`, and `y@#`, `y@#l`, `y@#r`, where `@#` is replaced by whatever suffix you use.
So if you call `pos1(b, d)` the macro will define `x1`, `x1l`, `x1r`, `y1`, `y1l`, and `y1r`.

Or rather it will define *some useful relationships* between them; in particular the six variables can be combined to define three points: `(x1l, y1l)`, `(x1r, y1r)`, and `(x1, y1)` -- through the usual plain MF convention that defines `z@#` as `(x@#, y@#)`, you can now refer to these three points as `z1l`, `z1r`, and `z1`, and they will be defined so that `z1` is exactly 1/2 way between `z1l` and `z1r` and that the distance between `z1l` and `z1r` will be `b` and the angle of rotation will be `d`.

Note that you will still need to define the location of `z1` at this point -- all that `pos` has done is establish where to put `z1l` and `z1r` when `z1` is known...

And what (you may ask) is the point of all this?  The answer is that is sets up the `stroke` macro...

#### The `stroke` macro

The definition of the `stroke` macro in `cmbase.mf` is quite hard to understand at first, but the net result is that it turns a non-cyclic path like `z1 -- z2` into a cyclic box path that you can fill.

In order for this to work, you have to define the extra `l` and `r` variable for each point.  Which is what `pos@#` does.  So provided you have already called `pos1` and `pos2`, then `stroke z1e -- z2e` will return the cyclic path

```
z1l -- z2l -- z2r -- z1r -- cycle
```

which you can pass to `fill`.  So to answer the OP question the difference is

- `fill z1e -- z2e;` is a mistake, you probably meant `draw z1 -- z2`.
- `fill stroke z1e -- z2e` will fill the box `z1l -- z2l -- z2r -- z1r -- cycle` provided the `l` and `r` suffixes are properly defined.

#### The answer

So having got through all that, I *think* the answer to the question "What is wrong?" is that the `crisp.nib` is so small that you can't see the line when you do `draw z1--z2` at the end.  The width may have rounded to a whole number of pixels equal to zero.  So since you have set `pos1` and `pos2` you might try doing `fill stroke z1e--z2e` instead.